# Keep only values that are unique across several arrays using Java 8 streams

Tags: java, arrays, java-8, java-stream

I want to keep only the unique values of two arrays after merging them using streams. It is not the `distinct()` function that I'm looking for:

```
int[] a = { 1, 2, 3 };
int[] b = { 3, 4, 5 };
int[] c = IntStream.concat(Arrays.stream(a), Arrays.stream(b)).distinct().toArray();
```

Gives me `c = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}`, but I need `c` to be `{1, 2, 4, 5}`

Is there an easy and fast way to achieve this using streams?

Comment: Can a value occur more than once in any of the arrays? If not, then solution is like this pseudo-code: `concat(a, b).group().filter(count == 1)`

Answer (score 4):

You can do this:

```
int[] a = { 1, 2, 3 };
int[] b = { 3, 4, 5 };
int[] c = IntStream.concat(Arrays.stream(a), Arrays.stream(b))
    .boxed()
    .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
        Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()), // Freq map
        m -> m.entrySet().stream()
            .filter(e -> e.getValue() == 1) // Filter duplicates
            .mapToInt(e -> e.getKey())
            .toArray()
    ));
```

This first creates a frequency map for all the elements, and then filters out elements that occurred more than once.

Comment: Thank you. That helps a lot. I think I can proceed from here.